# How can I solve at+cmss command returning error?

Tags: at-command

I am trying to send a sms from a gsm modem using AT command.

I ve tried following command

```
AT
OK

AT+CMGF=1
OK

AT+CMGW="+85291234567"
```

> A simple demo of SMS text messaging.

```
+CMGW: 1

OK
AT+CMSS=1
```

But last line **at+cmss=1** command returns error, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Command `+CMSS=<pos>` sends a message previouly stored memory in position  through `+CMGW` command.
This command can fail for plenty reasons, all basically related to trasmission issues. I cannot solve *your* problem, but I can provide a list of things to check in order to understand the reason of any network related operation failure:

1. Is the antenna connected? (who knows..)
2. Is the device registered to the network? Issue `AT+CREG?` and check the returned answer. `+CREG: x,1` and `+CREG: x,5`mean respectively that the device is registered to the home network or in roaming. Otherwise the registration is either still in progress or failed for some reason.
3. Has the Service Center number correctly been stored with `AT+CSCA` command?
4. Is the destination number correct?

Temporary network issues for your operator (not due to your device) can also lead to a SM sending failure.

But the universal attempt to be done during development phase is the *verbose response* enabling. Issue 'AT+CMEE=2' before the section where you get an error, and instead a generic `ERROR` response you will get something like `+CMS ERROR: <err>`, where  will describe the failure reason. Check the AT command user guide of the manufacturer of your modem in order to learn more about the error code you get.

Comment: Did you find the failure reason? I can help in case you're not able to translate <err> to the actual failure cause.

Comment: No, not yet. When i enter "at+cmee=2" command, it show only "error"

Comment: It's really strange, since it is a standard command and should be supported. Are you able to send SMS without storing them to memory? Try to issue `AT+CMGF=1;+CMGS=<dest number> (after +CMEE=2. Please note that it is a volatile setting, so that if you reboot the device you go back to +CMEE=0 default setting)

Comment: i used at+cmee? command and it showd +CMEE: 0.  does it mean the sms not sending because of the modem or antena?

Comment: i used command at+cmee=2 and it also shows "error". thanks for your help

Comment: Issue AT+CMEE=? (test command) in order to discover supported values.

Comment: the supported value is 0 when i issue at+cmee=?

Comment: Really? So you get `+CMEE: (0)`? So they don't support verbose errors? Cool..